# Prove that in a simple graph of diameter 2 the edge connectivity is equal to the minimum degree

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

A graph's diameter is the largest number of vertices which must be traversed in order to travel from one vertex to another when paths which backtrack, detour, or loop are excluded from consideration.
$$\operatorname{diam}(G)=\max\{d(u,v):u,v\in V(G) 
\}$$
The edge-connectivity of $G$, $\kappa'(G)$, is the minimum cardinal of the cuts in $G$.
$$\delta(G)=\min\left\{\operatorname{deg}(v):v\in V(G)\right\}.$$
Now i want to prove that for any simple graph with diameter 2, $\kappa'(G)=\delta(G)$.

Note: I know there exists a similiar proof for digraphs but I want to prove this theorem for simple graphs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inequality $\kappa'(G)\leqslant \delta(G)$ holds for any connected graph, since the edges incident to a vertex of minimum degree form an edge cut. For the reverse inequality, let let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $\operatorname{diam}(G)=2$ and $[S,\overline S]$ be a minimum edge cut with $|S|\leqslant |\overline S|$. Then every vertex in $S$ is adjacent to a vertex in $\overline S$. For if not, there would be a vertex $u\in S$ such that for each $v\in\overline S$, there is a path $u\to w\to v$ in $G$, which implies that $$|[S,\overline S]|\geqslant |\overline S|\geqslant \frac{|V|}2. $$ Then $\deg u\leqslant |S|-1<\frac{|V|}2$, so that
$$\delta(G)\leqslant d(u)<\frac{|V|}2\leqslant |[S,\overline S]|=\kappa'(G), $$
a contradiction. Since $|[S,\overline S]|= \sum_{v\in S}\deg v - 2e(G[S])$ , it follows that
\begin{align}
|[S,\overline S]|&\geqslant |S|\delta(G) - |S|(|S|-1)\\&\geqslant |S|\delta(G)-\delta(G)(|S|-1)\\&=\delta(G),
\end{align}
and hence $$\delta(G)\leqslant |[S,\overline S]|=\kappa'(G). $$

Comment: That was awesome !!! thank you !!! really thank you !!!

Comment: I don't quite understand how the first paragraph implies that $|[S,\overline{S}]| \geq |\overline{S}|$. By my understanding it would only imply that $|[S,\overline{S}]| \geq |S|$

Comment: @RaoulLuqué If $u\in S$ and $v\in\overline S$ with $uw$ and $wv$ edges in $G$, then either $w\in S$ or $w\in\overline S$. In the former case, $wv\in[S,\overline S]$; in the latter, $uw\in [S,\overline S]$. Hence for each element of $\overline S$ there exists at least one element of $[S,\overline S]$.

Comment: @Math1000 I see. I missunderstood the last sentence in the first paragraph. I thought the "which" in "which implies that" was refering to "Then every vertex in $S$ is adjacent to a vertex in $\overline{S}$", however it is refering to "there would be a vertex $u\in S$ such that for each $v \in \overline{S}$, there is a path $u\to w \to v$ in $G$". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $[S,\overline{S}]$ be a minimum edge cut. Suppose that $\lvert [S,\overline{S}]\rvert<\delta$, then we take an edge $uv$ from it where $u\in S,v\in\overline{S}$. For $d(u)\geq\delta>\lvert [S,\overline{S}]\rvert<\delta$, there exists $u'\in S$ adjacent to $u$. On the other hand, there exists $v'\in \overline{S}$ adjacent to $v$. Finally, we have a $3-$path $u'uvv'$, contradiction!