# Find simple graphs of diameter 3 where edge connectivity doesn't equal minimum degree

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

I've seen a question here which is about

> [Prove that in a simple graph of diameter 2 the edge connectivity is equal to the minimum degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681261)

But I would like to show that this is the best bound by finding an infinite class of connected graphs of diameter 3 where the minimum degree doesn't equal the edge connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the graphs obtained by joining two complete graphs on at least three vertices by a bridge; the number of vertices on each side need not be equal. The simplest case, with two copies of $K_3$, is

```
*     *
|\   /|
| *-* |
|/   \|
*     *
```

(MathWorld calls such graphs, with equal vertex counts on each side, [barbell graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarbellGraph.html)). All such graphs, by virtue of the bridge, are only 1-edge-connected; they are also easily seen to have diameter 3 and minimum degree at least 2. Therefore, this is an infinite set of diameter-3 graphs where edge connectivity and minimum degree are unequal.